# how to seperate classes in manifest?

Tags: java, android, manifest

I want to add two classes in accessibility service
I have tried this and its showing some errors of tag

```
<service
            android:name=".ClassGen1",".ClassGen2"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:persistent="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Why do you need two services for this?

Answer (score 0):

mistake in your code is writing class names with comma .

```
android:name=".ClassGen1",".ClassGen2"
```

Value of name attribute cannot be written with comma in android . You should declare them separately in different service tags . Like as below

```
<service 
    android:name=".ClassGen1"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:persistent="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service 
    android:name=".ClassGen2"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:persistent="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```